# Complex Query for Django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm trying to execute a complex query using Django's ORM and I can't seem to find a nice solution. Namely, I have a web application where users answer questions based on a video. I need to display all the videos for a specified user that have at least one question unanswered (not responded to). I haven't been able to figure it out yet with the ORM ... I know that I could probably write a SQL query for this and just execute it with the raw SQL function, but I really would prefer to stay in the ORM.

Models: Video, Question, Response and default User.

Relationships:

- Question has a many to many relation towards video
- Response has a foreign key each to Question, Video and User

What the query needs to do:

- Display all the videos for a specified user that have at least one video question unanswered (not responded to).

Any help would be awesome! I've been struggling with this for way too long.

EDIT: The models I have are (simplified):

```
class Video(TimeStampedModel):

     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     source_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Question(TimeStampedModel):

    DEMOGRAPHIC_QUESTION = 'd'
    QUESTION_TYPES = (
        (VIDEO_QUESTION, 'Video related question'),
        (DEMOGRAPHIC_QUESTION, 'Demographic question'),
    )

    MULTIPLE_CHOICE = 0
    PLAIN_TEXT = 1
    RESPONSE_TYPE = (
        (MULTIPLE_CHOICE, 'Multiple Choice'),
        (PLAIN_TEXT, 'Plain Text')
    )

    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION_TYPES)
    videos = models.ManyToManyField(Video, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    priority = models.IntegerField()

class Response(TimeStampedModel):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
     video = models.ForeignKey(Video, blank=True, null=True)
     choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, null=True, blank=True,related_name='selected_choice')
     text = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

// Not relevant but included for clarity
class Choice(TimeStampedModel):
     question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
     text_response = models.CharField(max_length=500)
     image = models.FileField(upload_to=_get_choice_img_path, blank=True)
     value = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     external_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: share the models you have. it would be easier to help that way

Comment: Question-Video is many to many?  Why?  Seems like each question is only about one video, even if each video has many questions.

Comment: Yes Question-Video is many-to-many because we want to be able to apply the same question to multiple videos. For instance - What was your favorite aspect of this video. That question applies to many videos.

Answer (score 0):

Judging logically by the way your models look like, I think something close to the following should be fine.

```
q = Response.objects.select_related().filter(user__name=user).filter(response__choice=None)

videos = Video.objects.filter(id__in=q.extra(where=["{}>=1".format(q.count())]).values('video_id'))
```

Hope you understand what I did there. The first line basically tries to take a natural join of the model objects. The second line is using the query generated in the first line to get the count and checks if it is at least 1, and gets the Videos that belong to that query.